# How to run one python file from another python file?

Tags: python

To start off, I am a beginner in python so I am not even sure if my question makes sense or is even possible.

I have 2 python files `app.py`. and `compare.py`. `compare.py` takes in two arguments (File paths) to run. So for example, when I want to run it, I do `python compare.py ./image1.jpg ./image2.jpg`. Now the return I get is some text printed to the terminal such as `Comparison Done, The distance is 0.544`.

Now, I want to run this `compare.py` from inside `app.py` and get a string with whatever `compare.py` would usually output to the terminal. So for example:

`result = function('compare.py ./image1.jpg ./image2.jpg')` and result will have the required string. Is this possible?

Comment: Without knowing more about the structure of `compare.py`, it's hard to say - it's possible, if it's sensibly written, that you can simply `import` the function with the appropriate behaviour and call it yourself.

Comment: Everything is possible as long as you put your mind to it ;) You may have to return these strings from one of the python functions  and import one `.py` file in the other to call that function . Yea, but hard to say without knowing the structure of these files.

Comment: Do you have control over the compare script? It might be nicer to import the compare script and call the compare functions directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.popen`:

In app.py:

```
import os
output = os.popen('python compare.py ./image1.jpg ./image2.jpg').readlines()
```

Comment: @AspiringMat glad to help!